# What is wrong with those crontabs?

Tags: cron

I want my projectors to Power On before the mall opens, and Power Off when the mall closes. So I created crontab entries (that I placed in /etc/cron.d/mall), but today (`Thu Nov 22 18:58:29 EST 2012` is the current `date` on that server), the power-off.sh script got executed at 17:20 (see syslog excerpt below).

Being Thu, Nov. 22, I would have expected the power-off.sh script to be executed at 21:20, per the 4th crontab line below.

Why did power-off.sh execute at 17:20? What is wrong with my crontab entries?

Content of `/etc/cron.d/mall`:

```
40  9 22-30 Nov Mon-Sat myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-on.sh
40 10 22-30 Nov Sun     myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-on.sh

20 18 22-30 Nov Mon-Wed myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-off.sh
20 21 22-30 Nov Thu-Fri myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-off.sh
20 17 22-30 Nov Sat-Sun myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-off.sh

40  9  1-22 Dec Mon-Sat myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-on.sh
40 10  1-22 Dec Sun     myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-on.sh

20 21  1-22 Dec Mon-Fri myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-off.sh
20 17  1-22 Dec Sat-Sun myuser /usr/local/projectors/power-off.sh
```

syslog excerpt:

```
$ grep power-off.sh /var/log/syslog
Nov 22 17:20:01 lanner-ubu-c2d CRON[23007]: (myuser) CMD (/usr/local/projectors/power-off.sh)
```

Comment: You aren't opening the mall ungodly early on Black Friday? :)

Comment: eheh. A good point, but living in Canada, we're not really touched by all this madness!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From crontab(5) man page:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields
>   day of month,  and day of week.  If both fields are restricted
>   (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches 
>   the  current time.  For example, `30 4 1,15 * 5` would cause a command
>   to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every
>   Friday.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess would be that it can't handle `Sat-Sun` because of this in the man page of `crontab(5)`:

> ```
> Names can also be used for the ``month'' and ``day of week'' fields.   Use
> the  first three letters of the particular day or month (case doesn't mat‐
> ter).  Ranges or lists of names are not allowed.
> ```

This means some of your lines are simply incorrect and will probably cause unexpected or at least undocumented behaviour.

Therefore, I suggest to change you day of week limits to numbers.

Comment: Superb. Thanks. I think I saw that paragraph many times, but never bothered to read the end!